# On pairwise rules engine

Tags: pairwise-testing, combinatorial-testing

I played with PICT `https://github.com/Microsoft/pict` but am unable to get it to express, or generate the test cases for the following:

```
Some things should never change.
action   : buy, sell
category : market, limit

Some things can change
duration : day, gtc
properties: tick_piot, penny
```

What I would like to do is to give PICT full control over things that can be optimized (`duration`, `properties`) and keep intact cases generated from `action` and `category`

**Example:**

```
buy, market, whatever
buy, limit,  whatever
```

How can I express this please. PICT solution is preferred. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
action : buy, sell

category : market, limit

change : day, gtc, tick_piot, penny

properties: tick_piot, penny, day, gtc

if [action] = "buy" then [category] = "market" or [category] = "limit";

if [action] = "sell" then [category] = "market" or [category] = "limit";

if [change] = "day" then [properties] <> "day" and [properties] <> "gtc";

if [change] = "gtc" then [properties] <> "day" and [properties] <> "gtc";

if [change] = "tick_piot"then [properties] <> "tick_piot" and [properties] <> "penny";

if [change] = "penny" then [properties] <> "tick_piot" and [properties] <> "penny";
```

Save script above as "test.txt" in any text editor. Run in pict with/o:x option, where x is 1,2 3 or 4 the order generation of test cases. One produce a test suite that covers all values only once (combinations of 1). It is optimal for finding bugs in short time. Two is pairwise, all pairs covered and default. With four you have all possible combinations (with constraints).

More help about Pict:
[Pict help online](http://www.amibugshare.com/pict/help.html#_Toc127249200)